# React, useEffect cleanup not working with removeEventListener, useRef, parallax effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, parallax, use-effect

I am trying to apply a parallax effect to an .svg image by using `useRef()` to grab `bubblesRef` and `translateY()` `onScroll`.

The parallax works but when I navigate to the next page I receive error "`TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`".  I think it is because the `addEventListener`  is still listening and trying to `useRef()` on `bubblesRef` while navigating to the next page.  So I added the cleanup function in `useEffect()` but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

p.s. If anyone can share their approach to a simple parallax effect like this that would be great too.  This is the only approach I've figured that won't rerender everything else on the page `onScroll`.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [loadedPosts, setLoadedPosts] = useState([]);
  const { sendRequest } = useHttpClient();
  console.log("loadedPosts homePage", loadedPosts);
  const bubblesRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadedPosts.length === 0) {
      //api call
    }
  }, [sendRequest, loadedPosts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const parallax = () => {
      let scrolledValue = window.scrollY / 3.5;
      bubblesRef.current.style.transform = `translateY(
      -${scrolledValue + "px"} 
      )`;
      console.log("scrolling...", scrolledValue);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", parallax);
  }, []);

  return (

      <HomePageContainer>
        <Header />
        <SectionOne posts={loadedPosts} />
        <SectionTwo />
         <BubbleBlobs className="bubbleBlobs" ref={bubblesRef} />
        <BlobTop className="backBlobBottom" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
      </HomePageContainer>
   );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: The error says `bubblesRef.current` is null.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Yeah I think it is becoming undefined when I navigate away from the HomePage but the event listener is still looking for it as I navigate away, so I try to add the cleanup function.  It isnt undefined until I navigate away.  I dont define it on the other pages because I dont use it on other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need the cleanup function any time you add a listener to the window, or the handler (and thus the component instance itself) will live on forever. However, since React runs those cleanup hooks asynchronously, it might not happen until after other window events. The value of the ref is set to `null` when the component unmounts, so you need to check that it is still defined before using the value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      // perform update
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handler)
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handler)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `useEffect`, your reference has not been instantiated, so the error message appears, in your `useEffect` dependency array, insert your ref and before running the code in `useEffect`, make sure your current reference is defined.